# e2fsprogs-l10n: Depends: e2fsprogs (>= 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3) but 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.2 is installed

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management

I ran into this problem when updating some software packages in Ubuntu 18.04.

```
e2fsprogs-l10n: Depends: e2fsprogs (>= 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.3) but 1.44.1-1ubuntu1.2 is installed
```

Comment: You need `ubuntu1.3`or higher but you have `ubuntu1.2`

Comment: Something you installed (most likely from a non-Ubuntu source) is requiring the lower version. You must figure out what it was and uninstall it. And preferably disable or delete that source.

Comment: @user535733 That seems like an answer. Would you be willing to post it (or something like it) as one?

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository bionic-updates
sudo apt update
sudo apt install e2fsprogs e2fsprogs-l10n
```